# Clear text field area in chrome console textarea class="form-control"

Tags: javascript

I'm using tool to put my products on amazon from my store. But I don't want to have descriptions from store on Amazon. I'm not similar with dev tools in browser, but maybe is it possible to remove this input with console in browser?

Code goes like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Product description" id="p0_description">Sample product description</textarea>
```

and I want to clear this "Sample product description, to be just "".

```
p0_description is for first product
```

then it goes like this:

```
p1_description is for 2nd
p2_description is for 3rd
```

and so on.

I found this, but I don't know how to automate this for all p0, p1, p2 etc..

```
$('#textareaName').val('');
```

Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$('#textareaName')` you can select elements by id, which must be unique for every element. What you want to do is select multiple items. You can do this with the element's class.

```
<textarea class="form-control description">
```

The selector for classes is `.`

```
$('.description').val('');
```